# When to save Android application-level data (not Activity data)

Tags: android, savestate

My Android app stores a potentially large amount of data in memory that it initially reads from a database. The reading of this data from the database into memory takes awhile, and I'd like to serialize and cache this data to a file between program runs, so that I don't have to read it from the database every time, hopefully speeding up application startup by eliminating database overhead.

This data is stored in a member of my Application class, not in my main activity. If I understand correctly, the Application class may persist when my main activity is destroyed and recreated (such as screen rotations). This is good. However, I need to know when the application itself is about to be destroyed (and I am thus about to lose the data stored in the Application class), so that I can cache it to a file before that happens.

I don't want to use onSaveInstanceState of my main activity, because that would cause the caching to happen more often than necessary (which I don't want to do, as it may be a somewhat expensive operation).

Is there a method of the Application class that I can override to handle this?

If not, are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the data in memory and work with it for maximum responsiveness.
Update the UI and save the data in database. If an error happens when saving new data notify the UI.
That way you don't have to worry about when the Application instance is destroyed.

Comment: As I stated in my question, I already keep the data in memory, and I already store it in a database. I think maybe you missed the question that I was asking.